# Extract JSON data with Data Flow - Flatten Transformation

Tags: json, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-factory

Following a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246504/azure-data-factory-extracting-information-from-data-lake-gen-2-json-files) I started working on a Data Flow, with the purpose of flattening a JSON file, created as a result of an Application Insights REST query. You can find an anonymised version [here](https://jsonblob.com/9446eac7-72d8-11eb-9d8e-cfc9bf096190).

My goal is to extract the data in the "rows" array of arrays, but I end up with the data duplicated in a cartezian manner (I got an original number of 18 rows and I end up with 324, 18*18).

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong or if it is an issue with the JSON "rows" array of arrays.

Here is my Data Flow - Source has the "Document per line" JSON option, "Single documents" raises a [unexpected character "] error, probably due to the strange formatting in the JSON:

[image]

This is the Data Preview in the Source - as you can see, it is only one "tables" node, with 18 elements in the "rows" array:
[image]
rows:

[image]

I tried to Flatten it, but I cannot map "rows" data to a column, I cannot use something like table.rows[0]:
[image]
Also, the rows data gets duplicated - 18 rows for each of the 18 rows outputted:
[image]

I am not sure how to get to the bottom of this, if it's the JSON format or if I am doing something wrong. From my experience it's probably the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by your special format.
Please try this:

[image]

1. add a `rowdata` property
   [image]
2. flatten your data
   [image]

Comment: I have tried that, but it returns a multiplied results (18 elements per 18 rows) similar to the last screenshot in my post - i cannot add a screenshot here in the comment

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Zhao thank you! But that solution duplicated the data similar to the original situation:
[image]

I did not manage to treat these data as JSON so I ended up thinking about it as text that can be manipulated into an array.

So I split the text by "rows:" and retrieve the second part of the split (arrays in Expression Builder start from 1):
[image]

[image]

Then I split that text as an array:

[image]

Which then I can flatten (at last):

[image]
[image]

From here on I keep splitting these values to get the data I need - I was interested in the first two and fourth column.